# how to store foreach return value in array and send two response in express?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-native, express

I tried to store the doctor details in array and display appointment and doctor Name Value response.
Appointment value is acheived but doctor Name Value comes empty even if it shows in console.

[image]

```
// get specific appointments of user
router.get("/user/:userId", async (req, res) => {

    try {

        console.log("user_id", req.params.userId);
        const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId);
        console.log("user", user);
        const uservalue = user._id;
        console.log("user_value", uservalue);
        const appointment = await Appointment.find({
            user_id: uservalue
        });
        console.log("appointments", appointment);
        const doctorNameValue = [];
        appointment.forEach(async element => {
            const doctor = element.doctor_id;
            const doctorDetails = await Doctor.findById({
                _id: doctor
            });
            doctorNameValue.push(doctorDetails);
            console.log(doctorNameValue);

        });
        res.json({
            appointments: appointment,
            doctorNameValue
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: err
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can get multiple `doctor_id` with Appointment.find:

```
const doctorIds = (await Appointment.find({
    user_id: uservalue
})).map(item => `${item.doctor_id}`));
```

The result of `doctorIds` is:

```
[ 
  "5dcfb0bf705db7342f1314e7",
  "5dcfb19c705db7342f1314e8",
  "5dcfb2d36faa53418c61127a"
]
```

Then, you can you `$in` in mongoose to find with an array `_id` like this:

```
const doctorDetails = await Doctor.find({
    _id: { $in: doctorIds }
});

console.log(doctorDetails)
// Here you can get arrayDoctorDetails Object

// Send doctorDetails to client
res.json({
    data: doctorDetails
});
```

**Remember: With Mongoose, you can use `$in` with an array string like above, but with Mongodb, you can not do that. With mongodb you have to convert to ObjectID("..") like this :**

```
$in: [ObjectId("5dcfb0bf705db7342f1314e7"), ObjectId("5dcfb19c705db7342f1314e8")]
```

Comment: How about finding doctor details that is redundant in the list? let's say there are two doctor same in the array?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it has to do with timing. you reach res.json before doctor gets resolved. try using Promise.all() in order to make sure you have the values before continuing like this.

```
Promise.all([appointment, doctorNameValue])
.then(()=>{
        res.json({
            appointments: appointment,
            doctorNameValue
        });
});
```

of course it means you’ll have to change your code a bit to accommodate for doctorNameValue

Answer (score 0):

You should send after the `forEach` loop is finished, try for the following:

```
var count = 0;
appointment.forEach(async element => {
            const doctor = element.doctor_id;
            const doctorDetails = await Doctor.findById({
                _id: doctor
            });
            count++;
            doctorNameValue.push(doctorDetails);
            console.log(doctorNameValue);
            if(count == appointment.length){
               res.json({
               appointments: appointment,
               doctorNameValue
               });
            }    
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait till the request is completed before doing foreach. One way to do it is

```
router.get("/user/:userId", async (req, res) => {
    res.then(resp => 
        // Store your response in array
    );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

async and await won’t work with loops that require a callback. Examples of such loops that require a callback include forEach, map, filter, and reduce.

JavaScript does this because forEach is not promise-aware. It cannot support async and await. You cannot use await in forEach.

Try to use async and await with either while or for-loop.JavaScript will pause the execution until the awaited promise gets resolved. This means awaits in a for-loop should get executed in series.

Try as suggested with for-loop or while and update if its working.

Answer (score 0):

Because the function in your `appointment.forEach()` is async, the forEach doesn't wait for each to finish before proceeding to the next. So when you reach your `res.json()`, none of the promises have resolved.

You're looking for:

```
const { userId } = req.params;
if( !userId ) return res.status( 400 ).json( { message: 'No userId provided.' } );

const user = await User.findById( userId );
if( !user ) return res.status( 404 ).json( { message: `User "${ userId }" not found.` } );

const appointments = await Appointment.find( { user_id: userId } );

/*
    Use new Set() to remove duplicates. I don't use
    Mongo so IDK if it does this automatically.
*/

const doctorIds =  [ ...new Set( appointments.map( ( { doctor_id } ) => doctor_id ) ) ];

const doctors = await Doctor.find( { _id: { $in: doctorIds } } );

return res.json( { appointments, doctors, user } );
```

However, this would be a good time to learn about [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

This isn't the most efficient method, but it follows closer to your initial approach.

```
/*
    Use Array.prototype.map() to return an array
    of promises from `Doctor.findById()`. Note that
    we are not awaiting.
*/

const promises = appointments.map(
    ( { doctor_id } ) =>
    Doctor.findById( doctor_id )
);

/*
    Promise.all() will only resolve once all promises
    in `promises` have resolved.
*/

const doctors = await Promise.all( promises );

return res.status( 200 ).json( { appointments, doctors, user } );
```

I guess the easiest way to explain `Promise.all()` would be:

```
/*
    Just some  async functions that resolve
    To strings.
*/

const calcFunc = async ( ) => {
    return 'Calc';
};

const searchFunc = ( ) => {
    return new Promise( resolve => resolve( 'Search' ) );
};

const promiseArray = [ calcFunc( ), searchFunc( ) ];

const [ calcResults, searchResults ] = await Promise.all( promiseArray );

console.log( { calcResults, searchResults } );

//Or

Promise.all( promiseArray )
    .then( ( [ calcResults, searchResults ] ) => {
        console.log( { calcResults, searchResults } );
    } );
```